# nginx rewrite to php-fpm with exception

Tags: nginx

My current rule set is:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
    }
```

I need to pass all the request to index.php;

Exceptions : **robots.txt** file and everything inside **images/** directory and sub directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the locations in the order:

```
location ~* /robots\.txt$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~* /images {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location / {
    try_files /index.php$is_args$args =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
}
```